# Reputation miscalculation when accepting my own answer?

Tags: support, reputation, self-answer

As you can see from the image below, today I have received 5 reputation from a question upvote. Also today I selected my own answer to one of my own questions. For some reason that selection has reduced my reputation by two points, as evidenced by the "3" reputation I have amassed for today.

Is that expected? I wouldn't think so as the "Tiling Simplex Noise" line in the Reputation breakdown seems confused, and in general docking points for answering your own question doesn't make sense either.

[image]

**Update:** Here is what stackoverflow.com/reputation reveals, which doesn't corroborate the above:

[image]

Comment: Hm. What does it say in http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?

Comment: [Hm, too](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/#post-172) ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had previously accepted [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6107161/1288) which you had received the standard +2 reputation for.  Accepting your own answer automatically unaccepted the old one, so you lost those 2 points.

Make sure the "show removed posts" box all the way at the bottom of your reputation tab is checked so it will show reputation changes for deleted posts.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; how does that match up with the latter screenshot? Even still, it would have been helpful for the interface to indicate '-2' for that question (bonus for a comment akin to "you changed the accepted answer to your own")

Comment: @fbrereto Did you trigger a recalc?  The old value of 16011 might be a cached value that just hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: I just triggered the recalc. No change.

Comment: I am just now seeing 16011 as my reputation on SO. What happened to the -2 that is suppsedly justified by my change? Was that a result of my triggering a recalc?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the checkbox, Bill -- I see it now!